# RxJava: Can you give me a real live scenario to use flatMap instead of map

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java

I can't really understand when to use flatmap instead of map, nor do I find a good example.
Can you come up with a good scenrio to choose flat map over map?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

For example, we want to do 2 requests, A and B, over web. However, request B must be requested after request A finishes because request B needs some result of request A. This is a good scenrio of `flatMap`. The example codes are as follow:

```
interface Movie {

}

interface UserInfo {
    List<Long> getFavoriteMovies();
}

public Observable<UserInfo> requestUserInfo(long userId) {
    // ...
}

public Observable<List<Movie>> requestMovieList(List<Long> movieIds) {
    // ...
}

public Observable<List<Movie>> requestUserMovieList(long userId) {
    return requestUserInfo(userId).flatMap(new Func1<UserInfo, Observable<List<Movie>>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<List<Movie>> call(UserInfo user) {
            return requestMovieList(user.getFavoriteMovies());
        }
    });
}
```

In addition, Ben Christensen's slide has some good examples of RxJava: https://speakerdeck.com/benjchristensen/rxjava-goto-aarhus-2013